# Simple Wordpress / PHP query

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a relatively simple question, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I'm looking to load a custom image size for each post and I want to do it by using the title of the subheading (A WordPress add-on). The reason I am using subheading and not 'heading', 'category' or 'tags' is because they are all playing a separate role within the site.

I need to take a simple WordPress command:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
```

And place the name of the subheading within it:

```
<?php if (function_exists('the_subheading')) { the_subheading(); } ?>
```

So it would look like this:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail('the name of the subheading here'); ?>
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (function_exists('the_subheading')) {
$subheading = get_the_subheading($postID);
the_post_thumbnail($subheading);
}
```

Note: $postID can be written also in other way, it depends how you are using the post id. Or just have **$subheading = get_the_subheading();**

Good luck!

Comment: I'm glad :) Just for curiousity, how it worked? With $postID or without it in your case? Thanks :)